# Convention for value that starts with numeric

Tags: rust, enums

I'm making a locale library in Rust and I need an enum for territories.

Most territory codes can represented as enum value, Uk, Jp, Kr ... . But there are some territory codes only contains numerics, such as 001, 002 ... etc.

So I wrote the enum like below.

```rust
#[derive(Debug, PartialEq, Eq)]
#[repr(u16)]
pub enum Territory {
    _001,
    _002,
    Us,
    Uk,
    Jp,
    Kp,
    Kr,
}
```

However, in Rust, names that start with an underscore have different meanings.
So I'm hesitant if this is the right way to go.

Is there any other way for this case? Are there examples of such cases in other well-designed library?

Comment: Are these used so commonly that a longer name is unsuitable? Something like `Unnamed001` perhaps?

Comment: @kmdreko 001 is not an unnamed area. In detail, 001 indicates world and 002 indicates Africa. There are, of course, long English names. But the territory codes should be language-neutral.

Comment: Maybe just `N001` then? You're going to have to choose some character.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a convention for this case specifically. I would suggest you pick a letter or a short word as a prefix. An example might be `Num001`, `Num002`, .... If you want to have your enum variants sorted and somehow the numeric values to be at the top or at the bottom of the list, even some artificial prefix like `Aaa` or `Zzz` might not be a bad idea.

Comment: My candidates are T001, T002 ... or _001, _002 as written in the question. Is this really bad idea starts with underscore? I wish the enum values were sorted..